# NodeJS http redirect request

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, npm

I am creating a simple NodeJs Server. Once this server gets a call, it does some things in the background and the user should be redirected to another page.
I am using this:

```
const http = require("http");

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    // do something

    res.end(); // This ends the request
    // Instead of ending the request (res), I want to redirect it to a specific url
}


server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, () => {
});
```

How do I do that for the http Module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a redirect response with the plain http module, you just need to manufacture the right type of redirect response and send that as the response.  A redirect response has a 3xx status code and sets the `location` header and would generally not include a body.

```
res.setHeader('location', 'http://wwww.google.com');
res.statusCode = 302;
res.end();
```

---

Keep in mind that a redirect response is just an instruction/suggestion to the client that they should go somewhere else to get the content they requested.  It's up to the client whether it actually follows the redirect or not.  A browser will automatically follow redirects in many circumstances.  But, an Ajax call using `XMLHttpRequest` from browser-based Javascript will not automatically follow a redirect.  Instead, the script receiving the response would have to examine the status code of 3xx, read the `location` header and issue a new request to the new http url.  Other http client libraries may have features you can enable to automatically follow redirects.

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: @BrainyXS - That means you've already sent the response before then trying to send a redirect.   You only get to send one response per incoming request.  You'd have to show the whole context and the actual code for us to advise more specifically.